# IF Function on excel - i need to put a formula into one cell using to < < however it isnt working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I need to put in one cell that IF the value of H3 and F3 is lower that 25000 but higher than 0 it will equal 29.95, if false 0

the formula 
=if(0

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the result of the comparison together using AND function.

First thing to do: checks if H3 is bigger than 0, and smaller than 25000 using the function below

```
AND(0<H3, H3<25000) --> #1
```

Then you will need to check for F3 (use same code above, change to F3) --> `#2`

Then you need to mix both result (Formula) together --> AND (#1, #2) --> `#3`

Then finally you can use #3 in your IF statement.

```
=IF(#3,29.95,0)
```

Does this make sense? Note: Copy and pasting the above will not work, you will need to think a little bit on how to add all those formula together.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(AND(H3>0,H3<25000),AND(F3>0,F3<25000)),29,95,0)
```

Hope this helps, best of luck!